# jQuery on click event firing multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I just learned how to use the method [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and I use it to add an event handler to some buttons that are added "live" (after the DOM is ready).

```
$('#table').on("click", ".delete", function() {
    //whatever
});
```

This seems to work fine but when I use it in my code I get the click event fired twice. It fires as many times as I have changed the selector, that is, I click a name in the selector and then another and another, let's say 3 times, then when clicking the mentioned button I will get an alert with all those 3 names instead of only the one is selected at that time.

I haven't been able to replicate it in a JsFiddle as the whole thing is quite big. So let me know what else I can add to make the question better.

**JS**

```
 $('#dataSelector').change(function() {
   #more code
    $('#table').on("click", ".delete", function() {
        var data_name = $("#dataSelector option:selected").attr('name');
        alert(data_name);
    });
  });
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="selectData">
    <label>Select:</label>
    <br>
    <div class="">

        <select id="dataSelector" class="form-control">

            <option id="default" selected="true" name="default">Pick</option>

            <option value="1" name="somethingA">somethingA</option>

            <option value="2" name="somethingB">somethingB</option>

            <option value="3" name="somethingC">somethingC</option>

        </select>


    </div>
</div>

<div id="goal_table" class="col-md-12">

    <table id="table" class="table table-bordered">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>Name1</th>
                <th>Name2</th>
                <th>Name3</th>
                <th>name4</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
            <tr id="13">
                <td>somethingA</td>
                <td>value</td>
                <td>whatever</td>
                <td>∞</td>
                <td>
                    <button name="13" type="button" class="btn btn-default delete"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</div>
```

Comment: I can't see any such thing in console. Tried catching and printing your event in console. Check this fiddle of your code:https://jsfiddle.net/Lrdntz07/..

Comment: Yes, as I said, I  haven't been able to replicate it but the accepted answer works so it's fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

just add off() before on() to remove existing event on it

there's a possibility that you already bind an event in that element so if you want to rebind the event you just off('event') to avoid firing event multiple times

```
$('#table').off("click").on("click", ".delete", function() {
    var data_name = $("#dataSelector option:selected").attr('name');
    alert(data_name);
});
```

Comment: As I want to learn, could you explain why? Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Since the event triggers multiple times it is bound more then once. Since we do not have the code to see where this actually happens, it is the easiest suggestion to unbind all click events before binding the new one.

Comment: I edited the question so it can be seen more clearly, but I get it now. I couldn't have figured it out alone. Thanks!

Comment: TBH: The better answer would is to only call `.on()` once and not multiple times, then you don't need `.off()`.  You use `.off()` when you're not sure where/how it's being wired up.

Comment: And what would be the point of having those handlers added, I mean, why isn't off before on the default behaviour?

Comment: Well, @freedomn-m, I went through my code and found out, of course, everytime the selector changed I was adding the handler. I put it inside it because I thought it was necessary due to the dynamically added buttons.

Comment: @DidinaDeen why did you bind your event inside change event anyway?

Comment: @NewbeeDev When the selector changes I ask the DB for details and then show it in the table (adding the necessary rows). I thought the click event had to be stated then, once I had the buttons created.

Comment: @DidinaDeen ah. so still the off().on() flow needed for this

Comment: No, I solved it taking the .on() out of the .change() but the off().on() flow worked too.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code, for me its working fine. may be in code you give same id for selector and delete button. please check and give unique name to each of your objects.

Comment: or else use... $('.delete').on("click", function() {
    var data_name = $("#dataSelector option:selected").attr('name');
    alert(data_name);
});

Comment: some buttons are created dynamically so that method won't work.

Comment: For that you have to user the method that you are currently using. but for me it triggered only once.